# Como puedo mostrar una cuenta descendente de elementos agrupado?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

En mi código tengo una tabla en la cual tengo datos agrupados, la idea es mostrar un contador de forma descendente de los datos agrupados, llevo rato tratando de poder solucionarlo, pero no puedo, me seria de gran utilidad si alguien me pudiera ayudar

[image: tabla]

El orden debería de quedar así

**2022-01 > 1

2022-02 > 1 2 3

2022-03 > 1 2**

```html
         $servername = "localhost";
         $database = "universidad";
         $username = "root";
         $password = "";
         // Create connection
         $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
 
         $sql = ("SELECT lapso, count(*) as cantidad FROM inscripcion WHERE cedula=24589635 GROUP BY lapso;");
         $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         echo "
             <table border=1>
                 <thead>
                     <tr>
                         <th>LAPSO</th>
                         <th>SABER</th>
                         <th>CURSO</th>
                         <th>TRAYECTO</th>
                         <th>ORDEN</th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>";
                $v=1;
         while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
           $sql1 = ("SELECT saber, curso, trayecto FROM estudiante est INNER JOIN inscripcion ins ON (ins.cedula=est.cedula) INNER JOIN saber sa ON (id_saber=sa.id) WHERE est.cedula='24589635' AND lapso='".$rows['lapso']."'");
            $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
            $cant = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
            echo "<tr>";
             if($cant>1)
                 echo "<td rowspan=$cant>$rows[0]</td>";
             else
                 echo "<td>$rows[0]</td>";
             while($rows1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
                echo "
                         <td>$rows1[0]</td>
                         <td>$rows1[1]</td>
                         <td>$rows1[2]</td>
                         <td></td>
                     </tr>
                 ";
              
            }
        }
         echo "
             </tbody>
             </table>
         ";
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Se me ocurre hacer un contador externo, que vaya sumando una variable que inicialice en 1, suma cada vez que recorre el segundo while y cuando sale de este comprueba después en el primer while si vale mas de 1, ejemplo 3, vuelve a 1

Comment: Creo que es buena idea, porque no lo intentas y nos dejas saber si tienes problemas

Comment: Si me funciono, ya deje la respuesta abajo por si alguien mas le puede suceder, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Bueno ya lo solucione jajaja era hacer un contador externo, que vaya sumando una variable que inicialice en 1, suma cada vez que recorre el segundo while y cuando sale de este comprueba después en el primer while si vale mas de 1, ejemplo 3, vuelve a 1, en este caso la variables externa es **$v**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
$v=1;
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$sql1 = ("SELECT saber, curso, trayecto FROM estudiante est INNER JOIN inscripcion ins ON (ins.cedula=est.cedula) INNER JOIN saber sa ON (id_saber=sa.id) WHERE est.cedula='24589635' AND lapso='".$rows['lapso']."'");
 $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
$cant = mysqli_num_rows($query1);
echo "<tr>";
if($v>1)
$v=1;
if($cant>1)
echo "<td rowspan=$cant>$rows[0]</td>";
else
echo "<td>$rows[0]</td>";
while($rows1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)){
   echo "
     <td>$rows1[0]</td>
     <td>$rows1[1]</td>
     <td>$rows1[2]</td>
     <td>$v</td>
   </tr>
";
$v++;
```